# Difference between 心臓 and 心

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words, kanji

What's the difference between [心臓]{しん・ぞう} and [心]{こころ}—both seem to mean "heart".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

心臓 refers to the organ and 心 to emotions and feelings.

I took the following from [プログレッシブ英和中辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/heart/#ej-39501).

心臓:

> heart problems
> 心臓病
>
> My heart stood still.
> （驚いて）心臓が一瞬止まった

心:

> have a kind [tender, gentle] heart
> 優しい心をしている
>
> a heart of gold [stone]
> 優しい［冷酷な］心
>
> a change of heart
> 心がわり
>
> My heart goes out to you.
> 心から同情します
>
> I loved him with all my heart and soul.
> 心の底から彼を愛した

---

Note that 心臓 also has a figurative sense as in Xの心臓部, meaning the most important part/center of X.